# Work with MTOM in Lotus Notes

Tags: java, soap, lotus-notes, mtom

We have a task to  create Lotus Notus Web Service Consumer, which uses MTOM.
Can anybody help t o create it?
I have tried to create Web Service Provider, but it does not work.
Here is code of Provider:

```
 @MTOM(enabled= true)
 public class Mtomservice{  
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public Response getResponse (byte[] arg0) {
    Response response = new Response ();
    try{
        String filePath = WebServiceBase.getCurrentSession().getEnvironmentString("Directory", true)+"/PretenzMtom_3.pdf";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        fileOut.write(arg0);


        response.setResponseststus("OK");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setResponseststus("error");
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

        response.setResponseErrorText(errors.toString());

    }

    finally {
        return response;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it does not work". Does it crash? Does it hang? Does it throw an exception? Something else? Tell us exactly what you expect to happen, and tell us exactly what actually happens. Otherwise, nobody can help you.,

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1. Import your WebService WSDL in Designer.
2. Put all code from auto-generated WS into Java ScriptLibrary.
3. Use Library in Consumer.
4. If you do not have WSDL, you can write it yourself.

The another and the best way:
Use "Domino OSGi Task" and plug-in, but for this you need install "OpenSocial Component" on server. This task run around HTTP task. How? Google, pls, there are many examples in WWW.

And for all this you need Domino 9.0.1+

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I am writing Web Service Provider.